# How to work around DataSet.toJSON being incompatible with Structured Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I want to write data from Twitter into Kafka. For educational purposes, I try to do this using Structured Streaming. I have created a Twitter-Source, based on the socket-Source, which works well.

I set up my source as follows:

```
val tweets = spark
  .readStream
  .format("twitter")
  .option("query", terms)
  .load()
  .as[SparkTweet]
```

This gives me a nice DataSet for analytical queries. Great!

Next I want to persist each tweet in the slightly sparkified schema into Kafka:

```
val kafkaOutStream = tweets
  .toJSON.as("value")
  .writeStream
  .queryName("stream_to_kafka")
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("1 second"))
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092")
  .option("topic","tweets")
  .start
```

That's easy! Except, it doesn't work. In `QueryExecution.scala` the call passes into `assertSupported` and eventually gets thrown out, because

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
    Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
```

I didn't expect `toJSON` to be a pure batch-op, but without it, and using say `select($"text" as "value")` instead, the code will work.

Now, I'm slightly flabbergasted and would love for someone to explain why toJSON shouldn't be streaming-compatible (is it a bug? a missing feature?), and tell whether there's a Structured Streaming-way of getting a serialized representation of my object into Kafka.

Comment: @user6910411 I don't think the edited title correctly represents the content of the question. After all, the question and answer are all about DataFrame.toJSON, and its implementation details in that particular version of Spark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit verbose but `to_json` function should do the the trick:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{to_json, struct, col}

tweets.select(to_json(struct(df.columns map col: _*)).alias("value"))
  .writeStream
  ...
```

The problem with `toJSON` seem to be [this conversion to RDD](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L2738):

```
val rdd: RDD[String] = queryExecution.toRdd.mapPartitions { iter =>
  ...
```

and (as pointed out by [maasg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/764040/maasg) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45614364/sparks-dataset-tojson-is-not-structuredstreaming-compatible-how-to-convert-a-d/45614984#comment78190232_45614984)) seems to be already resolved in the development version.

Comment: Cool, this appears to work around the issue. Hopefully sql.functions and DataSet API will achieve a higher degree of parity for structured streaming in the near future.

Comment: @RickMoritz it seems to be solved on master already: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L2929